# Guessing game program with a while loop, where users enter a number and the computer tells them if it right, or to guess higher, or lower

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop

My program continues to tell the user to guess lower, even if the user types in the correct number. How do I solve this?

```
import random 
a=raw_input('enter a number')
b= random.randrange(0,11)
while a!=b:
    if a < b:
        print ('you are not correct, try a higher number')
    if a > b:
        print('you are not correct,  try a lower number')
    if a== b:
        print('wwcd')
    print b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems with it as currently are that `a` is never updated & that you are using `'a'` the character rather than `a` the variable

```
while `a`!=b:
```

Compares a constant character to the number b (and will always be larger). It should be:

```
while a!=b:
```

This change should be applied to all your conditional statements (also it's probably best to remove the repeated     `if 'a'== b` blocks, as only one is needed)

For the next part you need to update `a` as part of the loop (such that the user can change the input). You only need to move the part where you assign `a` a value downwards:

```
while a!=b:    
    a=raw_input('enter a number')
    //rest of your conditionals statements
```

EDIT:

You have a 3rd problem. The `raw_input()` function returns a `string` and you need an `int` for comparison. To fix it simply cast it to int: `int(raw_input('Enter a number'))` or, more appropriately use Python 2.x's `input()` function. This will evaluate anything you input so will return `int` when you enter a number. But watch out, Python 3.x `input()` acts like `raw_input()` in 2.x and `raw_input()` is gone.

Comment: how is moving a into the while statement going to work, because then it is not defined, and it says that a is not defined.

Comment: My apologies that was unclear. Simplest way would be to copy it rather than moving, so you do it during your loop as well as before it starts. Or you could just define `a = -1` or any other value that will not be the same as `b`

Comment: I am editing all of these things, but my program still continues to tell the user to enter a lower number, even if the number us right.